# Heap corruption on deleting a pointer twice stored in different classes

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, heap-corruption

Two classes A and B share pointer to a third class C and when either A or B are deleted they call delete C as well.

Issue is not observed when only either of A or B is deleted.
An exception is getting thrown in this scenario. I have specifically tried to set the class C pointer to NULL and have put in a NULL check to avoid this specific scenario but this null check is somehow not working.

I have read around that shared pointer should be used in this case but I am not sure how to implement it properly. It looks like whole code base needs to be changed to include shared_ptr everywhere as all class C objects would be updated to shared_ptr. Is there a way I can use shared_ptr just to store this pointer without changing all the code?

**Edit:**
I have specifically deleted assignment operator and copy constructor of C to avoid situation both have different pointers due to copying. Can anything else can be done to prevent copying as pointed in answer by john

```
class A{
  C* c;
}
~A(){
  if(C != NULL){
  delete C;
  C = NULL;
 }
}

class B{
 C* c;
}

~B(){
  if(C != NULL){
  delete C;
  C = NULL;
 }
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself the question _"Who (what object) is the owner of `c`"_ ?  When you can answer this clearly we can suggest a way forward. (Owner is the object(s) responsible for  creating and destroying `c` ie controlling its life-time).

Comment: Yes, I agree, ownership needs to be clear here. I am seeking workaround for time being till I architect this in a better way.

Comment: This is the kind of scenario that `std::shared_ptr` was invented to solve.

Comment: Agree on usage of shared_ptr, not sure how to implement properly it in my case. My impression is that would require a lot of code restructuring unless I find some example demonstrating proper implementation.

Comment: You don't show the initial creation of `c`.  Re-architect that to create use `std::make_shared` (instead of `new`) and then always use copies of the returned `std::shared_ptr` in places where you currently have `C*` ie option (2) from the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A` and `B` have separate copies of the pointer to `C`. So setting one classes copy of that pointer to `NULL` has no effect on the other pointer and you still get a double delete.

You have basically four options

1. Decide that one class 'owns' the pointer, that class will delete it and the other will not. The danger here is that if the owning class deletes the pointer and then the non-owning class uses the pointer then you are going to get a different kind of error.
2. Use shared ownership of the pointer, so that it only gets deleted when the last object using it gets destroyed. The easy way to do that is to use `std::shared_ptr`

   ```
   #include <memory>

   class A {
       std::shared_ptr<C> c;
   };

   class B {
       std::shared_ptr<C> c;
   };
   ```

3. Clone the pointer before copying it to the second class. Something roughly like

   ```
    a.c = new C();
    b.c = new C(*a.c);
   ```

this way both classes get separate (but equal) copies of the `C` object. But this changes the semantics of your program, maybe you actually want `A` and `B` to share the same `C` object.

4. This option (suggested by Richard Critten) has class `A` having a `std::shared_ptr` and class `B` having a `std::weak_ptr`. This means that `A` owns the `C` object, and when the last `A` object has been destroyed the `C` object will also be destroyed. Any remaining `B` objects do not prevent the destruction of the `C` object but, the `B` object can check whether the `C` object has been destroyed. In code it looks something like this

   ```
   #include <memory>

   class A
   {
       std::shared_ptr<C> c;
   };

   class B
   {
       std::weak_ptr<C> c;
   };

   class C
   {
        C(whatever);
   };

   A a;
   B b;
   // create a shared pointer
   a.c = std::make_shared<C>(whatever);
   // create a weak pointer referring to the same C object
   b.c = a.c;

   // create a shared pointer from the weak pointer in b
   auto c = b.c.lock();
   // check if the pointer is valid
   if (c)
   {
        // do something with c
        c->something();
   }
   else
   {
        // c object has been destroyed
   }
   ```

Comment: (4) Sole owner `std::shared_ptr` and handout `std::weak_ptr`s instead of raw observer pointers.  That way the observers can monitor the potential destruction.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have specifically deleted assignment operator and copy constructor of C to avoid situation both have different pointers due to copying.  Can anything else can be done to prevent copying?

Comment: @stackUnderflow What is being copied is the **pointer** to `C`. Deleting the assignment operator and copy constructor for `C` has zero effect on that. In fact the only effect is to rule out option 3.

Comment: @stackUnderflow Option 4 from Richard Critten is a good one, which I didn't think of, you should consider that as well.

Comment: @stackUnderflow Of course a fifth option is not to use pointers in the first place. They are often used by beginners when they are not necessary.

Comment: Maybe I am asking for too much, can you provide a snippet of what Richard has suggested? Any link would be helpful as well.

Comment: @stackUnderflow Not right now, I'm off to watch the football. I'll update later maybe

Comment: Sure, have a good time!